# In the output of `git diff`, what do the first two lines mean?

Tags: git

In the output of `git diff`, what do the first two lines mean?

Specifically, in the following two examples:

What do `diff --git a/file b/file` and `diff --cc file` mean? I thought they mean that `git diff` is invoking `diff`, but does `diff` have options `--git` and `--cc` (`man diff` doesn't show them)?

What do `index a29c52b..802acf8 100644` and `index 4d77dd1,802acf8..0000000` mean? (Is `index` followed  by a range of commits and a commit?)

```
$ git diff
diff --git a/file b/file
index a29c52b..802acf8 100644
--- a/file
+++ b/file
@@ -2,3 +2,5 @@ Line 1 stuff
 Line 2 stuff
 Line 3 stuff
 Line 4 alternate stuff
+Line 5 alternate stuff
+Line 6 alternate stuff

$ git diff
diff --cc file
index 4d77dd1,802acf8..0000000
--- a/file
+++ b/file
@@@ -2,5 -2,5 +2,10 @@@ Line 1 stuf
  Line 2 stuff
  Line 3 stuff
  Line 4 alternate stuff
++<<<<<<< HEAD:file
 +Line 5 stuff
 +Line 6 stuff
++=======
+ Line 5 alternate stuff
+ Line 6 alternate stuff
++>>>>>>> alternate:file
```

Comment: Looks like a commit hash but I'm not positive

Comment: First looks like a standard diff, the second looks like a conflict diff.

Comment: Side note: you'll have to dig through answers other than the accepted one to find what the `index` line means, but just search for `index`.